# Operation canceled Error in Linux EC2 while running powershell script from Node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell, amazon-ec2, exchange-server

I am trying to run a powershell script from my node.js application.
The powershell script takes the input as "email" and deletes the contact from Microsoft Exchange. The scripts works fine in local machine but throwing error in AWS EC2 Linux instance.

Here is the script to delete the mail contact from MS Exchange, named as delete.ps1

```
param(
    [string]$email
)

$connectionPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'User Password' -AsPlainText -Force
$coneectionString = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("User Email", $connectionPassword)
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $coneectionString

$contact = Get-MailContact -Identity $email

if ($null -ne $contact){
    $contact = Get-MailContact -Identity $email | Remove-MailContact -Confirm:$false
    Write-Host "Contact is deleted for the user alias: $contact"
} else {
    Write-Host "Contact is not found for the user alias: $contact"
}

Write-Output $contact`your text`
```

I am using the exec command from "child_process" package in node.js.
The code to call the powershell script is:

```
 await exec(
            `pwsh ${scriptPath} -email ${email}`,
            { timeout: 600000 },
            (error: any, stdout: any, stderr: any) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
                    this.logger.error(
                        `Error: ${error}`
                    );
                    return;
                }

                console.log(`Output: ${stdout}`);
                this.logger.info(`Success!!`);
                return stdout;
            }
        );
```

The code works completely fine when I am running locally on my system [MacOS].

But, when I hosted the code on AWS EC2 Linux instance, it started throwing the error: `(7.2.7:A:80) [NamedPipeIPC_ServerListenerError:NamedPipe.Exception.Error] An error has occurred in PowerShell IPC listening thread on process: 17186 in AppDomain: None.  Error Message: Operation canceled.`

A complete log for this is:

```
[Perftrack_ConsoleStartupStart:PowershellConsoleStartup.WinStart.Informational] PowerShell console is starting up

[NamedPipeIPC_ServerListenerStarted:NamedPipe.Open.Informational] PowerShell has started an IPC listening thread on process: 17186 in AppDomain: None.

[Perftrack_ConsoleStartupStop:PowershellConsoleStartup.WinStop.Informational] PowerShell console is ready for user input

[NamedPipeIPC_ServerListenerError:NamedPipe.Exception.Error] An error has occurred in PowerShell IPC listening thread on process: 17186 in AppDomain: None.  Error Message: Operation canceled.
```

I tried adding a timeout to the node.js code block while calling the script, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: It appears the listener stopped working when a connection was attempted.  The two usual reasons is the TLS that is used for encryption failed or OAUTH authentication failed.  I think the issue is occurring before any email commands are issued. Using a username and password is no longer secure.  Either Default Credentials are used or AUTH2 is used.  AWS uses OAUTH2 authentication.

Comment: Installing the cmdlet modules made the thing work. But now, it's taking almost 5-10mins to process each request and is generating dozens of script blocks. 
Like: [ScriptBlock_Compile_Detail:ExecuteCommand.Create.Warning] Creating Scriptblock text (338 of 338) @jdweng